# getting foreign key value without fetching the entire object?

Tags: django, django-models

say I have these models:

`class Parent(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField()

class Child(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField()
    parent = models.ForeignKey('Parent')`

I want to create a `dict`:

`{x.parent.pk : x.slug for x in Child.objects.all()}`

this code generates a separate database query for each iteration. just to get the `Parent` object, just to get its primary key. which is right there in the `Child` object to begin with! I do not need anything from the parent, just its primary key. How do I get the value of the underlying foreign key?

(yes, I know that I can use `select_related()` to get rid of these extra queries, but my question is not about that.)

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work

```
{x.parent_id : x.slug for x in Child.objects.all()}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a nice shortcut for this, which gets just the parent IDs and slugs so is more efficient:

```
dict(Child.objects.values_list('parent_id', 'slug'))
```

Comment: Cool use of values_list and dict! Somehow, I don't think I've ever used values_list as an instant key-value map.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
{x.parent.pk : x.slug for x in Child.objects.select_related('parent')}
```

**EDIT**

Sorry. Misunderstood exactly what you wanted. You should be able to just do:

```
{x.parent_id : x.slug for x in Child.objects.all()}
```

Comment: I tried that, it works :), as I noted in my question, I am interested to find out whether there is a way to get the key from the Child table without joining the Parent table.